# ASP.Net Razor view uses cached value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a Problem with my ASP Razor views.

I have an Action which takes the model, manipulates it and then uses `PartialView` to display the result (The partial view is the same as the one used for the postback).

The model gets updated just fine, but the view engine renders the old values and not the new values. So `EditorFor` does not use the new model value but instead uses the value that the model had when it got posted.

I have applied the `OutputCache` attribute to my action:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

But this does not change anything.

Also I know that this is no client caching problem as the result returned by `EditorFor` already has the wrong value set.

**EDIT**
Here is the full code of the action. It basically calls a Service which saves the data und updates the Model.

```
[HttpPost]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(StaffingCostRatesForYearViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        vm = await TryAsync(() => Client.UpdateStaffingCostRatesAsync(vm), vm, x => RestoreDropDowns(x), "Fehler beim Speichern");
    }
    else
    {
        await RestoreDropDowns(vm);
    }

    return PartialView("EditorTemplates/StaffingCostRatesForYearViewModel", vm);
}
```

As the Model contains a List, i found out that the problem does not occur when i use BeginCollectionItem. But as this is no dynamic List, it shouldn't be neccessary.

Comment: If you remove the `OutputCache` directive does the issue still exists?

Comment: Yes, removing the attribute has no effect.

Comment: Can you provide you're actions code?

Answer (score 0):

Add Model.Clear() before returning the view.
I've had this same problem. Another mostly unrelated problem is that some attributes posted blank values, while others were fine. This fixed that for me too.

Answer (score -1):

Just for testing try to use plain HTML (no HTML helpers) control and bind value.